# create cloud function with trigger cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function from the serverless framework, and setting as a trigger that is activated when files are created in a bucket, but it doesn't work and I can't find more information about this in the documentation

serverless.yml

```
read-file:
handler: ReadFile
events:
  - event:
      eventType: providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/google.storage.object.archive
      resource: "projects/${self:provider.project}/buckets/${env:BUCKET_NAME_GS}"
memorySize: 128
environment:
  AUDIENCE_AUTH0: ${env:AUDIENCE_AUTH0}
  DOMAIN_AUTH0: ${env:DOMAIN_AUTH0}
```

serverless response:

```
{
"code":400,
"message":"The request has errors",
"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"event_trigger","description":"Unknown event_type providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/google.storage.object.archive"
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory for you using serverless framework ? it's really simple to trigger a Cloud Function with an event in Cloud Storage with `gcloud` cli and without a specific framework.

Comment: @MazlumTosun if it is necessary to be able to upload the changes through that cli